# Modify default help message (-h) in OPTPARSE , python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The default help message in `optparse` regarding to (-h) is:

> show this help message and exit.

How can I change this message to more useful message?

I have seen some guy said: "You should be able to replace the default help mechanism with your own merely by subclassing OptionParser and overriding the `print_help()` method."

But since I'm new to Python I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `add_help_option = False` to `OptionParser` constructor and then define a help option on your own. Alternatively, subclass `OptionParser` and override `_add_help_option()` method.

**EDIT**: Alternative method (with overriding) is not a good idea generally, since the method is "private" and not documented, so could go away in a future version.

**EDIT 2**

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser (add_help_option = False)
parser.add_option ('--lol', help = "do nothing")
parser.add_option ('-h', '--help', action = 'help',
                   help = "this is the new help")

options, args = parser.parse_args ()
```

And:

```
$ ./test.py -h
Usage: test.py [options]

Options:
  --lol=LOL   do nothing
  -h, --help  this is the new help
```

Comment: Dear doublep,  soppuse the new help would be: "this is the new help" will you write the exact code?

Comment: Dear doublep, Thanks for the reply, now I can customize the relating output of -h, but thing is in the output of "filename. py -h" there are still helps relating to other arguments as well! For example, I have defined "-i" to specify the input file and this -i have its own help as well, but I can see the help of -i in the output of -h!